# How to auto-size iframe height within jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, iframe

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Stepy](http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/), which is based of the [FormToWizard](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx) plugin, to allow users to complete a 10-step form.

I am also using the code from the [jQuery iFrame Sizing](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing) tutorial to auto-size the iframes on my page; however, the auto-resize does not appear to be functioning properly within the Stepy plugin.

On my application, the inline style height is set to "0" after the page loads when I look at the code in Firebug.

I setup a fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wvkfn/3/

If you look at the HTML in the fiddle, Step 2 has an iframe in it (which is not displaying). If you remove the code to load Stepy, it appears correctly.

Any ideas what is going on?